# Partial Derivative of Exponential Quotient

Tags: exponential-function, partial-derivative

How would I go about finding the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of $z = (x^2/(1-y^3))^{0.5}$

The way I thought to do it was to get rid off the brackets and square root, making $x/(1-y^{1.5})$.  However, I have the answer for this problem (given by a book), and it does not match the answer given by doing it this way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: I should add that the answer of the partial with respect to X did match the method I used to solve this problem.

Comment: can you specify which one of function you want to find its derivative

Comment: The first one, partial derivative with respect to y

Comment: Pls note: $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-y^3}}$ does not equal to $\frac{x}{1-y^{1.5}}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(1-y^3)}}=|x|(1-y^3)^{-0.5}$$
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=|x|(-.5)(1-y^3)^{-1.5}(-3y^2)=\frac{1.5y^2|x|}{\sqrt{(1-y^3)^3}}=1.5y^2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{(1-y^3)^3}}$$

Comment: It was x divided by the 1-y bit.

Comment: @Harkell you mean the answer?

Comment: I mean the question

Comment: @Harkell sorry,check my answer again,

Comment: Thankyou for your help my friend, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u = 1 - y^3$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: Would I not have to use the quotient rule?

Comment: It's a partial derivative wrt $y$ so you can treat $x$ as constant.